# how to i implement a create a account in log in page in JavaFX using filehandler

Tags: java, exception, javafx

hi I'm trying to make a database basically logs you in. but before that can happen you need to create an account,

```
@FXML
void buttonPressed(ActionEvent event) {

    String username= txt_username.getText();
    String password =txt_password.getText();

    FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("user");


    try {
        fh.createSaveFile("pass");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();}

    }
```

this is what I have it says it makes a file but when I try to log in it gives me a exception?

```
void buttonClicked(ActionEvent event)
{
    String username= txt_username.getText();
    String password =txt_password.getText();

    FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(username);

    try
    {
        if(fh.checkKey(password))
        {
            //TODO: goto main application
            System.out.println("Login successful with u: " + username + " p: " + password);
            gotoBrowse(username, password);
        }
        else
        {
            String hint = fh.getHint();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect password, please try again. Your hint is: " + hint, "invalid credentials", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println("Login failed with u: " + username + " p: " + password);
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid username, please try again", "invalid credentials", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println("Login failed with u: " + username + " p: " + password);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An unknown error has occured. Please try again or try restarting the application.", "unknown error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An unknown error has occured. It is possible your password save file has become corrupted.", "unknown error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
this is the login function
```

what is causing it
Basically all I want to know is how do I create an account and save their details in the files,

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: ok I have made a  login page application using scene builder.

Comment: I want to create user so a user can register and then log in successfully the issue I am getting it that when I create file, and then try to log in with those same details that were used to sign up, the program takes ages to load and crashes,

Comment: sorry not create file but create user***